# Adding a Mesh File with QGIS (3.22.4 Bialowieza) : Exception std::bad_alloc Error Message

Tags: qgis, netcdf, mesh

When I try to add a NetCDF file as a mesh file in QGIS, I have the following error message

**Exception**

**std::bad_alloc**

The NetCDF file is ***202392013465222_BGIForestAgeMPIBGC1.0.0.nc***

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Is it a RAM issue ?